# Scala, trasform filter/foreach of map into For Comprehension

Tags: scala

here my code: (Variables to use. Is it possible to create a For Comprehension also here instead of foreach? In this code i search all username into players and put it into playersToLobby)

```
      private var players: Seq[GamePlayer] = _
      private var totalVotes: Int = this.numberOfPlayers
      private var playersToLobby: Map[String, Int] = Map.empty

      this.players.groupBy(_.username).foreach {
          case(username, _) => this.playersToLobby = this.playersToLobby + (username -> 0)
      }
```

Then, in this code, i take inside playerToLobby a player with high votes and reset playerToLobby setting it to map.empty. Then i filter gamePlayer to find all alivePlayer and added the all username of alive players into playersToLobby.

```
    val playerToEliminate = playersToLobby.maxBy(_._2)._1
    this.playersToLobby = Map.empty

    gamePlayer.filter(p => p.username != playerToEliminate && p.isInstanceOf[AlivePlayer]).
      groupBy(_.username).foreach {
      case (username, _) => this.playersToLobby = this.playersToLobby + (username -> 0)
    }
```

How can i trasform it into a For Comprehension? I have to trasform this into a for comprehension, please, help me ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Some case class for a GamePlayer with username and age.

  ```
  case class GamePlayer(username: String, age: Int)
  ```
- Change variables to values (as they are immutable/final).

  ```
  val gamePlayers: Seq[GamePlayer] = Seq(GamePlayer("me", 30), GamePlayer("you", 25), GamePlayer("eliminate_me", 19))
  val playerToEliminate = GamePlayer("eliminate_me", 19)
  val lobby = Map.empty
  ```
- Some fake method is checking if the player is alive (replace this with your logic).

  ```
   def isAlive(player: GamePlayer): Boolean = player.age > 28
  ```
- The for comprehension. Note that I didn't transform what you had in a for comprehension, I tried to understand why you started from those foreach and groupBy, but without further insight I just assume you are still getting a grasp for what for comprehension is. So, I just made some example of it.

  ```
  for {
    p <- gamePlayers
    if p.username != playerToEliminate.username && isAlive(p)
  } yield lobby + (p.username -> p)
  ```

This will basically take players from the gamePlayers sequence, filter them and add them to the map.